# How to test the value of all items in a container?

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x, containers

Let's say I have a container such as a dictionary or a list. What is the Python way to test if all of the values of the container are equal to a given value (such as `None`)?

My naive implementation is to just use a boolean flag like I was taught to do in C so the code could look something like.

```
a_dict = {
    "k1" : None,
    "k2" : None,
    "k3" : None
}

carry_on = True
for value in a_dict.values():
    if value is not None:
        carry_on = False
        break

if carry_on:
    # action when all of the items are the same value
    pass

else:
    # action when at least one of the items is not the same as others
    pass
```

While this method works just fine, it just doesn't feel right given how wonderfully Python handles other common patterns. What is the proper way to do this? I thought perhaps that the builtin [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function would do what I wanted but it only tests the values in a boolean context, I would like to compare against an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still use `all` if you add in a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
if all(x is None for x in a_dict.values()):
```

Or, with an arbitrary value:

```
if all(x == value for x in a_dict.values()):
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `x is not None` to be consistent with the `carry_on` in the example?

Comment: I think that the example is incorrect because the OP said: "What is the Python way to test if all of the values of the container are **equal** to a given value (such as None)?"